# @NotNull constraint don't work for a application property value spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to prevent a NotNull value of a application property.

In my application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
         my-property: classpath:a/b.json
```

my Property class:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver")
public class ABCProperties {

    @NotNull
    private URI myProperty
```

When the value of application property is empty, i don't have a constraint violation exception.

How can i prevent that the value of application property is null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `@Validate` to your `ABCProperties` as follows:

```java
@Data
@Validated
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver")
public class ABCProperties {

    @NotNull
    private URI myProperty;
}
```

As a side note, as of Spring Boot 2.2, Spring finds and registers `@ConfigurationProperties` classes via classpath scanning. As a consequence, you do not need to annotate such classes with `@Component` or `@Configuration` or even use `@EnableConfigurationProperties`. If you are using a Spring Boot version that is newer than 2.2 you can remove `@Configuration` from your `ABCProperties` class.

Comment: Seems strange, but I don't get it working in same case.

Comment: In order to be able to help you I would suggest you create a new question ;)

Comment: No need, your solution was not worked for my because I have nested objects to be validated. I found out that adding `@Valid` above the field along with your proposed `@Validated` on the whole class do the thing. You can edit your answer to help others) Or let me add the answer for nested objects.

Comment: You can always add the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you have nested objects which fields must be validated, you need add `@Valid` to that nested object class member declaration:

```
@Data
@Validated
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver")
public class ABCProperties {

    @Valid
    private MyComplicatedProps myProperty;

    @Data
    public static class MyComplicatedProps {
        @NotNull
        private URI uri;
}
```